# failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd'

Tags: spring, schema

While starting my Spring App, I am getting the following error :

```
WARNING: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document     
'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd', because
1) could not find the document;
2) the document could not be read;
3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

My springapp-servlet.xml is as follows :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"      
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
<bean name="/hello.htm" class="springapp.web.HelloController"/>
</beans>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly you changed?

Answer (score 4):

When I got this error message, it was merely because of a missing jar in my CLASSPATH.  Some spring applications seem to be very hungry for spring jars.  My app wound up needing all of these on the classpath:

```
${OTS_DIR}/org.springframework.aop-${VERSION}.jar:\
${OTS_DIR}/org.springframework.aspects-${VERSION}.jar:\
${OTS_DIR}/com.springsource.org.aopalliance-${AOPALLIANCE_VER}.jar:\
${OTS_DIR}/org.springframework.asm-${VERSION}.jar:\
${OTS_DIR}/org.springframework.beans-${VERSION}.jar:\
${OTS_DIR}/org.springframework.context-${VERSION}.jar:\
${OTS_DIR}/org.springframework.core-${VERSION}.jar:\
${OTS_DIR}/org.springframework.expression-${VERSION}.jar:\
${OTS_DIR}/org.springframework.jdbc-${VERSION}.jar:\
${OTS_DIR}/org.springframework.jms-${VERSION}.jar:\
${OTS_DIR}/org.springframework.orm-${VERSION}.jar:\
${OTS_DIR}/org.springframework.transaction-${VERSION}.jar:\
${OTS_DIR}/org.springframework.instrument-${VERSION}.jar
```